# RSelenium rsDriver setup error in open connection to bitbucket

Tags: r, selenium, rselenium

I have just installed RSelenium. However, I think I lack a dependency, because when I try to use `rD <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome")` (also with phantomjs or firefox), the following error appears.

```
>Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : 
  cannot open the connection to 'https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/ariya/phantomjs/downloads?pagelen=100'
In addition: Warning message:
In open.connection(con, "rb") :
  URL 'https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/ariya/phantomjs/downloads?pagelen=100': status was 'SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK'
```

I have also tried to set up a webdriver for chrome, but the same error appears.

Comment: Hey
Have you found a solution to your problem? I am receiving now a similar error and RSelenium was working just fine a few days ago
Edit: Nevermind. Seems like the bitbucket is doing maintenance on their servers

Comment: Hey @U_jex, I set it up as `rsDriver(browser = "firefox", port = 4567L, chromever = NULL)`, I think there was an issue with the chrome version driver RSelenium installed, which wasn't compatible with the Chrome version I had at the time. `chromever = NULL` solved this.

Comment: Hey @Alberto Agudo Dominguez
Yes, I also have to define the chrome version like you. That behaviour appeared out of nowhere.